# Command line grep gives wrong results

Tags: grep

I have two files, one with the patterns of a grep search, and the other is the target file where I want to look for patterns.

File 1 looks like this:

```
Cre01.g001800
Cre01.g001950
g46
g46
Cre01.g002050
Cre01.g002150
RPB6
g51
Cre01.g002201
Cre01.g002201
Cre01.g002236
Cre01.g002236
Cre01.g002300
```

And my second file looks like this:

```
chromosome_12   scriptAPG   exon    3691112 3693536 .   +   .   gene_id "RPS11";transcript_id "RPS11"
chromosome_9    scriptAPG   exon    3011840 3038275 .   -   .   gene_id "Cre09.g387400";transcript_id "Cre09.g387400"
chromosome_9    scriptAPG   exon    2571100 2572801 .   +   .   gene_id "Cre09.g390678";transcript_id "Cre09.g390678"
chromosome_14   scriptAPG   exon    3804470 3817534 .   +   .   gene_id "Cre14.g632650";transcript_id "Cre14.g632650"
chromosome_3    scriptAPG   exon    4400340 4417459 .   +   .   gene_id "Cre03.g175600";transcript_id "Cre03.g175600"
scaffold_40 scriptAPG   exon    36  2671    .   +   .   gene_id "g18380";transcript_id "g18380"
chromosome_6    scriptAPG   exon    7445801 7457337 .   -   .   gene_id "Cre06.g300050";transcript_id "Cre06.g300050"
chromosome_17   scriptAPG   exon    584317  595135  .   +   .   gene_id "Cre17.g699950";transcript_id "Cre17.g699950"
```

My aim is to extract the rows in `file2` that have some pattern in `file1`. So, I throw the following command:

```
grep -w -F -f ".$out."/localization/prep/translator.txt localization/prep/locations.gtf > localization/prep/genemodels.gtf
```

What I am not understanding is: why the output file from the grep search, genemodels.gtf, have lines without matching patterns? It prints all the lines!! Doing this:

```
grep Cre01.g003600 translator.txt
```

I do not obtain any results. However, doing this:

```
grep Cre01.g003600 genemodels.gtf
```

I obtain:

```
chromosome_1    scriptAPG   exon    688996  690516  .   +   .   gene_id "Cre01.g003600";transcript_id "Cre01.g003600"
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong? Could it be the point `.` that some patterns to look for (e. g. `Cre01.g001950`) have? Grep does not sees that as a literal point. How to avoid that?

Thanks.

Comment: For starters, none of your lines in File 1 matches any of the lines in the second file.

Comment: Just trying to clarify -- your text says that you are getting false positives ("lines WITHOUT matching patterns") but your examples says you are NOT getting results you want. Which is it? The latter?

Comment: Of course, both. If I am having lines without matching patterns, I am not getting the results I want.

Comment: This totally works. I added a match to file 1 to demonstrate http://pastebin.com/Ku18xnJu

Comment: jurgemaister, you say it works, but you are not doing `grep -w -F -f`.

Comment: It works for me even if I add `-w` and `-F` https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gts0oc6thl3ggv/Screenshot%202014-06-13%2014.03.42.png Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Have you got a blank line in File1? That will match.

Comment: Do you want me to upload my files, this way you can test if that works?

Comment: Solved, I just added `""` around the patterns in `translator.txt` and it works good. Thanks to everybody that tried to help.

Comment: @user2979409 Since you solved it yourself, you may want to post an answer so that it is more clear for the next people entering in this page.